# Using array results from ruby gsub method and a match block

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm working through the Ruby koans and have hit one that's really confusing me.

```
"one two-three".gsub(/(t\w*)/) { $1[0, 1] }
 => "one t-t"
```

However, when I modify the return array for the $1 variable, I get a confusing result.

```
"one two-three".gsub(/(t\w*)/) { $1[1, 2] }
 => "one wo-hr"
```

Given the first result, I'd expect the second bit of code to return "one w-h". Why are two characters being returned in the second instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You expect "one w-h" which would be the result of this:

```
"one two-three".gsub(/(t\w*)/) { $1[1, 1] }
```

`[]` is a [method on string](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) where a range can be provided like so:

```
str[start, length]
```

so the 2 in your code is actually the length (i.e. number of characters)